# Merging two dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge two data frames of city housing costs data using Pandas.

Comment: Unless you have a dictionary/map of the abbreviations, You cannot merge the two

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you will need to replace all the abbreviations with the full name of the city before merging. However, this should be fairly simple but a bit tedious. Also for future posts, please attach some code and examples of your data for reference.

```py
df1.replace(['BOS', 'NYC', ...], ['Boston', 'New York City', ...])
```

Comment: thanks for the info, I'll be sure to do so in the future